# Break Main Calling Thread If Child Thread Throws An Exception

Tags: python, multithreading, exception

I'm using threading.Thread and t.start() with a List of Callables to do long-running multithreaded processing. My main thread is blocked until all threads did finish. I'd like however t.start() to immediately return if one of the Callables throw an exception and terminate the other threads.

Using t.join() to check that the thread got executed provides no information about failures due to exception.

Here is the code:

```
import json
import requests


class ThreadServices:
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = ""

    def execute_services(self, arg1, arg2):
        try:
            result = call_some_process(arg1, arg2) #some method
            #save results somewhere
        except Exception, e:
            # raise exception
            print e

    def invoke_services(self, stubs):
       """
       Thread Spanning Function        
       """
       try:
           p1 = ""  #some value
           p2 = ""  #some value
           # Call service 1
           t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.execute_services, args=(a, b,)

           # Start thread
           t1.start()
           # Block till thread completes execution
           t1.join()

           thread_pool = list()
           for stub in stubs:
               # Start parallel execution of threads
               t = threading.Thread(target=self.execute_services,
                                          args=(p1, p2))
               t.start()
               thread_pool.append(t)
            for thread in thread_pool:
                # Block till all the threads complete execution: Wait for all 
                the parallel tasks to complete
                thread.join()

            # Start another process thread
            t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.execute_services,
                                           args=(p1, p2)
            t2.start()
            # Block till this thread completes execution
            t2.join()

            requests.post(url, data= json.dumps({status_code=200}))
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            requests.post(url, data= json.dumps({status_code=500}))
        # Don't return anything as this function is invoked as a thread from 
        #  main calling function


class Service(ThreadServices):
    """
    Service Class
    """

    def main_thread(self, request, context):
        """
        Main Thread:Invokes Task Execution Sequence in ThreadedService        
        :param request: 
        :param context:
        :return: 
        """
        try:
            main_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.invoke_services,
                                       args=(request,))
            main_thread.start()
            return True
        except Exception, e:
            return False
```

When i call Service().main_thread(request, context) and there is some exception executing t1, I need to get it raised in main_thread and return False. How can i implement it for this structure. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, you are complicating matters too much. I would do it this way:

```
from thread import start_new_thread as thread
from time import sleep

class Task:
    """One thread per task.
    This you should do with subclassing threading.Thread().
    This is just conceptual example.
    """
    def __init__ (self, func, args=(), kwargs={}):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.error = None
        self.done = 0
        self.result = None

    def _run (self):
        self.done = 0
        self.error = None
        self.result = None
        # So this is what you should do in subclassed Thread():
        try: self.result = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except Exception, e:
            self.error = e
        self.done = 1

    def start (self):
        thread(self._run,())

    def wait (self, retrexc=1):
        """Used in place of threading.Thread.join(), but it returns the result of the function self.func() and manages errors.."""
        while not self.done: sleep(0.001)
        if self.error:
            if retrexc: return self.error
            raise self.error
        return self.result

# And this is how you should use your pool:
def do_something (tasknr):
    print tasknr-20
    if tasknr%7==0: raise Exception, "Dummy exception!"
    return tasknr**120/82.0

pool = []
for task in xrange(20, 50):
    t = Task(do_something, (task,))
    pool.append(t)
# And only then wait for each one:
results = []
for task in pool:
    results.append(task.wait())
print results
```

This way you can make task.wait() raise the error instead. The thread would already be stopped. So all you need to do is remove their references from pool, or whole pool, after you are done. You can even:

```
results = []
for task in pool:
    try: results.append(task.wait(0))
    except Exception, e:
        print task.args, "Error:", str(e)
print results
```

Now, do not use strictly this (I mean Task() class) as it needs a lot of things added to be used for real.

Just subclass threading.Thread() and implement the similar concept by overriding run() and join() or add new functions like wait().

Comment: Thank You  @Dalen. This approach worked for me at least. Some workaround and it kicked off.